# spawn python ENOENT error with node child process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying to call a python script as a child process within a node script. The output of the script is to be used within a callback. The code looks like this:

```
//myFunction.js

const myFunction = callback => {
  let py = process.spawn('python', ['../folder/pyscript.py'], {
    cwd: '../folder/'
  });

  let str = '';

  py.stdout.on('data', data => {
    str += data.toString();
  }

  py.stdout.on('end', () => {
    callback(str);
  }
}

exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

This code works as expected when I directly run node myFunction.js (with an instance of myFunction within the script) and it works fine when I require the module in any other files within the *same directory as myFunction.js*.

But it fails with the following error when the module is required in a different higher level directory:

```
error: spawn python ENOENT
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with paths (value of cwd maybe?) but I can't seem to fix this. I've looked up similar questions but the answers aren't helping.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: `../folder/pyscript.py` is a relative path, of course it depends on the correct cwd. Did you try an absolute path?

Comment: I think I missed your comment back when I asked this, but you may be correct. I'll add an answer to my own question in order to help any future askers. Thanks! :)

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65008091/8119511

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue is with the cwd. Everything in the script is relative to the path of the directory *from where the script is invoked*. So basically, running `node myFunction.js` from the project root directory (say `~/projects/myProject` would set the cwd to `~/projects/myProject/../folder` which would evaluate to `~/projects/folder`. This is obviously incorrect, since in all probability, no directory named `folder` exists on the system, and thus this would lead to an `ENOENT` error.

The solution would be to construct the absolute path of your script in the code, perhaps by using the `__dirname__` property in combination with the functionalities provided by the `path` module.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for days, before realizing that my script file was not getting picked up and spawned by nodeJS, because of some `filepath` issue.

Although I don't guarantee this will work for everyone, depending on their setup, this is what I did in my nodejs file:

```
let py = process.spawn('python', [__dirname + '../folder/pyscript.py']);
```

As you can see, I didn't have to use the `{cwd: '../folder/'}` option.

If your script is in the current directory as your javascript file, just do

```
let py = process.spawn('python', [__dirname + './pyscript.py']);
```

I should also point out that:

> process.spawn('python', ['./pyscript.py']);

never worked for me and I spent days wondering why. Could find an answer until I tried this technique. Hope someone having this issue find this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using ${process.cwd()} worked for me... you can write it like this

```
let py = process.spawn('python', [`${process.cwd()}/folder/pyscript.py`]});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ubuntu machine then probably we have only python3 is added to the environment variables by default. Try to **change the process name from python to python3**

```
let py = process.spawn('python', [__dirname + './pyscript.py']);
```

to

```
let py = process.spawn('python3', [__dirname + './pyscript.py']);
```